# How to interpret any kind of HTML wrapping container (div, ...) in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

So I am having a hard time defining how to interpret a wrapping container from plain HTML to ReactJS.
Here's an example which will explain what I mean.

HTML code:

```
<body>

<header>
    <div class="fixed-header">
        ...content
    </div>
    <div class="primary-header">
        ...content
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <article class="card">
       ...content
    </article>
    <article class="card">
       ...content
    </article>
    <article class="card">
       ...content
    </article>
    <article class="card">
       ...content
    </article>
    <article class="card">
       ...content
    </article>
</main>

</body>
```

So from this code, I want to make 3 React components:

1. fixed header
2. primary header
3. article element

The problem is that elements 'header' and 'main' are wrapping containers and they have some CSS style applied to them that actually affects child elements inside them and because of that I can't just get rid of them.
I already made three react components: FixedHeader, PrimaryHeader and Card. The problem now is how to implement 'header' and 'main' elements in ReactJS, something like this:

```
<header>
   <FixedHeader/>
   <PrimaryHeader/>
</header>
<main>
   <Card/>
   <Card/>
   <Card/>
   <Card/>
   <Card/>
</main>
```

I don't want to make them components because they are just wrappers and also I don't want to use React.Fragment for them because CSS can't be applied to Fragments as far as I know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: I have a plain HTML file (like the one in the post) and I am trying to divide into reusable React components. I already made 3 components (those in the post), but the problem is I don't know how to specifically implement 'header' and 'main' elements as React components, because functionally 'just being wrappers' doesn't make them suitable for React components. In plain HTML they have some CSS style applied to them and if I just removed them, the majority of the page would not look how it looks with them. I hope i made it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're afraid that you can't use `<header>` and `<main>` element in React.

If so, don't worry. You can use any html elements in React JSX. That's perfectly valid. You don't need to transform every html elements in component. Transforming html elements to component is only for reusability. If you don't need to repeat the code, you can simply write plain html elements in JSX, they will be rendered by it.

---

The only problem I can see is you can't render siblings in React. You'll need to use `<Fragment>`:

```
return (
  <>
   <header>
     <FixedHeader/>
     <PrimaryHeader/>
   </header>
   <main>
     <Card/>
     <Card/>
     <Card/>
     <Card/>
     <Card/>
   </main>
 </>
)
```

`<></>` is alias for `React.Fragment`.

If you don't want to use `Fragment`, then you can simply wrap them with `<div>`.

When you wrap elements with `<></>`, the browser will not render it. But it will render contents inside of this. So, you'll get exactly like you had in your html. So, you don't need to worry for the further css to style it.

Comment: Okay, but how can I then write that in React? If I try the React code from my post, I get " Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?" and the error points to the <main> element. Basically, I want a React component inside a HTML element, but I am getting that error.

Comment: Oh, totally unintentionally ignored the last sentence. Can you point me out what should I do in terms of writing in JSX? As you can tell I am a React newbie, so I am grateful for the help.

Comment: You can write exactly like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to be concerned about creating components as you have mentioned. It creates cleaner, more modularised code that is easier to maintain and reuse.

You can create light, stateless components and [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and still apply styling as needed.

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-brook-d4ylo?file=/src/App.js)

Some example code from the above demo:

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

// stateless, pure functional component
const Header = memo(props => (
  <header className="header">
    {props.children}
    <hr />
    <nav>
      <a href="/" title="home">
        home
      </a>
      &nbsp;
      <a href="/about" title="about">
        about
      </a>
    </nav>
    <hr />
  </header>
));

const Card = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick} value={props.name}>
      {props.name}
    </button>
  );
};

const allCards = [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }, { name: "baz" }];

export default function App() {
  const [cards] = useState(allCards);

  const onClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.info(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header>
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </Header>
      <main>
        {cards &&
          cards.map((card, index) => (
            <Card key={index} name={card.name} onClick={onClick} />
          ))}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I flagged the asnwer from @Bhojendra Rauniyar as correct, but yours is also accurate. Thank You!